Apache Camel GraphQ SSL/mTLS
I am working on Apache Camel GraphQL component and as per Apache camel Document, everything is working fine. Facing issue to make Secure HTTP Request.
I tried HTTP component and enabled SSLContext with all required certificate. Still my API manager complain about that there is no certificate is available in the request
Checked the Apache camel doc as well and there is no query parameter (or option) to enable or disable secure communication.
I am using Apache Camel 3.1 with XML DSL
